# Progressively loading slide: Some images don't load or only load partially and quit

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, lazy-loading, slideshow

I'm progressively loading my images using [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I noticed that some of the images are either partially loading or not loading at all.

For example, on [this site](http://keebs.com/dax), there are two galleries: Architecture and Design (in the nav). When the user clicks on either one, they are presented with a list of the images within that gallery. The problem happens when I switch from one gallery to another. So if I'm looking at an image in `Architecture` and I click on `Design > x.jpg`, the new image either doesn't load at all or partially loads and quits.

Here is a screenshot. It only loads that small strip and quits. Also, it seems that that exact amount gets loaded anytime I face this problem. No more, no less.

[image]

Below is what I'm using to switch galleries.

```
$('#main').on('click','.change_gallery',function() {

    $('.side-nav').removeClass('active');
    $('.side-nav').hide(0);
    $('.side-nav').css('z-index', 1);
    var mygroup = $(this).data('group'); // gets the group name
    var position = $(this).attr('rel'); // gets the index

    if (mygroup == cgallery && (typeof cgallery != 'undefined')) {
        var position = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', position, false);
    } else {

        $('.slider').fadeTo(500,0, function () {         

            // Destroy previous slider
            if (typeof cgallery != 'undefined') {
                $('.slider').slick('unslick');
            }

            $('.slider').html('');
            if (mygroup=="Design") {
                $('.slider').html($("#image-containerb").html());
            } else {
                $('.slider').html($("#image-container").html());
            }

            // Load images
            $('.myslide').each(function() {

                // Add landscape and portrait classes to style accordingly
                var $this = $(this);
                var iwidth = $this.data('iwidth');
                var iheight = $this.data('iheight');

                if ($this.data('iwidth') > $this.data('iheight')) {

                    $this.addClass('landscape');

                } else {

                    $this.addClass('portrait');
                }

                var header_height = $('.site-header').height();
                var footer_height = $('.site-footer').height();
                var cheight = window.innerHeight - header_height - footer_height - (6*16);

               $this.css('height', cheight);
                $this.css('max-height', cheight);

            });

            $('.slider').fadeTo(500,1);

            var $slider = $('.slider').slick({
                fade: true,
                focusOnSelect: true,
                speed: slider_speed,
                cssEase: 'ease',
                lazyLoad: 'progressive',
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 3000,
            });

            $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo',position,true);

            $slider.find('.slick-slide').on('click', function() {
                $slider.slick('slickNext');
            });

            $('.slick-prev').show();
            $('.slick-next').show();

            var header_height = $('.site-header').height();
            var landscapeH = window.innerHeight - (header_height+64+44);
            $('.portrait, .slick-slide').css('max-height', landscapeH);

            cgallery = mygroup;

        });

    } // end else
});
```

Initially, I thought it was because the large image needed time to load, so I tried placing my mouse over the partially loaded strip of the image (to prevent autoplay from moving onto the next image), however, it just ended up never loading.

What could be causing this?

Comment: It is extremely hard to troubleshoot since the issue does not happen every time and the times it does, it doesn't last long. I got 2 theories: Animation is slow and hiding the overflow or the image does not get fully loaded quick enough.

Comment: are there certain browsers this happens in more then others?

Comment: @ViruZX Yeah, I realize that it's difficult to troubleshoot due to the inconsistency of how often it happens. However, on my end, it happens a lot more than it doesn't. If the image does not get fully loaded quick enough, shouldn't it continue to load if I place my mouse over that strip to prevent autoplay from moving onto the next slide?

Comment: @DannyBlue I think it's pretty consistent across all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing `adaptiveHeight:true` to `adaptiveHeight:false` and it seemed to take care of it.

Comment: I recommend you to preload the images by setting background image to a temporary div before showing it in the slide. Also have onload event to the image before showing it in the slide. I had the same problem. But no more after the CSS trick.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter which image is loaded first you can do

```
$('#yourclass').slick('slickGoTo', 2);
```

it will jump to the next image which will be loaded fine.

Comment: While this might work I don't think it's very user-friendly to jump to a different slide with no reason.